# Migrating to .NET6: Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 not found on TC machine

Tags: migration, .net-6.0, dotnet-sdk

#### Background

I want to migrate my repository form .NET5 to .NET6. As there are many projects, the plan is to do it in multiple steps. So it's an intended intermediate step to have some of the projects targeting .NET5 while some other set to .NET6.

I use a personal NuGet feed and the official `nuget.org` is disabled.

As the first step, I updated `global.json`

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.201",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

which previously used to target version `5.0.201`.
I made sure `6.0.201` is installed on my machine by using `dotnet --list-sdks`

```
╰─ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Then I chose a subset of the projects contained in the repository and changed

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Everything compiles without a problem. Not even a single warning.

However, Team City machine can't build the repo. I'm getting the following error for all the `net5.0` projects (so: the **not** migrated ones)

```
NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, MyLocalNuGetCache
```

I've searched through my machine, but it doesn't contain the package `Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64`. Despite this fact everything builds nicely.

Also, running `dotnet --list-sdks` on my TC machine proves that `6.0.201` is installed:

```
╰─ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

#### Questions

- What is `Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64` needed for and how can I find it on my machine?
- What's the best starting point for an investigation to see why doesn't my repo build on the TC machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of debugging this I've gone down to the root of the problem.

1. To get explanation about the `Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64` package see [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602173/what-is-microsoft-netcore-app-host-win-x64-used-for).
2. As there's no way to specify multiple versions of SDKs in `global.json`, I wrongfully assumed that SDK 6.0.201 contains also a set of system libraries for .NET5. My not-yet-migrated projects started complaining at missing 5.0.15 packages (e.g. EF Core), so I downloaded them and placed in my personal feed.
3. The reason for MSBuild to pick up 5.0.15 was that that was the latest .NET SDK installed on my machine.
4. However, the corresponding .NET SDK (in this case: 5.0.406) was not installed on my TC machine.

That's a quick summary.

I'm going to need both .NET6 and .NET5 apps in my repo - at least for some time. The fact that I can't pin SDK version for both targets in `global.json` is very misleading. It's already caused a lot of problems and I expect more dragons to show up in the future.